# SAP Hybris Update description of Front Tile Component

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I am new to Hybris and I still do not know how impex works.
I would like to know how to make an impex script to update a description of a front tile component.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find here the syntax of the impex file :

https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/1c8f5bebdc6e434782ff0cfdb0ca1847.html#loio1c8f5bebdc6e434782ff0cfdb0ca1847

Basically it's a csv file (semicolon-separated) with specific structure/header,

```
mode type[modifier=value];attribute[modifier=value];attribute[modifier=value];attribute[modifier=value]
```

- **mode** : action to be executed -> INSERT, UPDATE, INSERT_UPDATE, REMOVE.
- **type** : item to be processed -> Product, Category, Customer,...
- **attribute** : the attribute of the item -> Product.name, category.description,...
- **modifier** : additional information to process an attribute -> unique, lang, ...

---

Example :

Assuming we have the following Item type :

```
public class ProductModel {

    private String code;

    private String name;

}
```

The impex to import Products would be like :

```
INSERT Product  ;code[unique=true]  ; name[lang=en]         ;name[lang=fr]
                ;123456;            ; This a product name   ;nom du produit
```

---

To answer your question specifically -> to Update the description of a front tile component, thte impex file should be something like :

```
INSERT_UPDATE Name_of_the_Component ;code[unique=true]      ; description[lang=en]
                                    ;code of the component  ; The description to update
```

Comment: Hello Mouad, Thank you so much for this.